# Does a voltage source produce current on an open branch?

Tags: thevenin

[image: Circuit]

I am supposed to find the Thevenin equivalent of this circuit however the branch with the 30V source is confusing me. I know that if there was only a resistor in that branch then no current would flow in that branch. However is that still the case when there is a voltage source there? I think that there will be no current in the branch because there is no return path but the 30V will still add to the open source voltage. Is my logic right?

Comment: What did the question say was happening between points A and B?

Comment: There would be a load between a and b of which I need to find the Thevenin equivalent circuit for. The circuit is open there for the purpose of finding the open circuit voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there will be no current through the 30V voltage source either. If there was, then that current would have no way to go to or come from if **a** is kept floating. This would violate Kirchoff's Current Law in node **a**.

If you add a load between **a** and **b**, then you are closing a loop and it becomes possible that a current flows through the 30V voltage source.

Comment: Thank you. And also if I were to work out the open circuit voltage between node a and b, would I have to still add the 30V to that value despite there not being any current there?

Comment: Yes! Voltage sources do not care about currents, they just produce voltages.